# How to generate Public Private key pairs for digital signatues in node.js?

Tags: node.js, meteor, digital-signature

Im developing an application in meteor.js. In this application a user "A" will send some data by signing it with its private key on to the server. So any other user "B" can verify it by decrypting the data with public key of "A". Now the problem is i dont know that how can I generate pub/priv key pairs for multiple user so that they can verify each other signatures.

Comment: Try [searching](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=digital%20signature) npmjs , you may find something that meets your requirements

Answer (score 1):

By running the following command

-N means the RSA passphrase
-C User's email address
-f The location of the new RSA key pair

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa -N "" -C "username@example.com" -f ~/.ssh/random_id
```

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const randomId = '';
const userEmailAddress = ''
const baseLineCommand = `ssh-keygen -t dsa -N "" -C "${userEmailAddress}" -f ~/.ssh/${randomId}`;
exec(baseLineCommand, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  // New RSA key key pair has been successfully generated
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

Comment: Can you think of a solution that doesn't use `exec` ? Maybe it's better to let users generate the keys and upload the public one to the server?

Comment: If you let a user generate their RSA key pair, how about you set a body-parser and make a RESful route and let they post their key via the HTTP payload body?

Comment: Thanks @FelixFong Can you please guide me how can I read gernated public private key pairs from directory i.e .ssh/random_id at the time of signing?